# Accessing Deployment Target in unit test code

Tags: ios, xcode, build-settings

I need to know my deployment target in my unit test cases. Is there any way to get the iOS deployment target programmatically (using Objective-C)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Displays as a 'big' int:

```
NSLog(@"Deployment target: %i", __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED);
```

e.g. for iOS 5.1 as the deployment target

```
Deployment target: 50100
```

Comment: Nope. I am not talking about device. I am talking about ios deployment target from Xcode.

Comment: In that case, try __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED defined in Availability.h

Comment: No dealing with build variables, simple, just the odd int formatting to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

This [is available as an Xcode build variable](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html) called `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`.

All you need to do is create a preprocessor macro holding that value:

[image]

and then you can refer to `AMIT_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` in your code. (Note: this is a `float`, rather than the string you might expect.)

Comment: I like your answer but @Rob Glassey answer is much simple. But thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's better, too; I wasn't sure those two macros were equivalent.